# Activex prompt not promptly disappearing

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, unsigned, activexobject

I am instantiating an instance of the file system object in java-script with activex [var fso = new ActivexObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")]  and as expected I get the prompt to allow this interaction or not.

My question is, when I respond "Yes" the prompt stays on the screen to long for any page updates or ajax response to write to the document. I've tried setting timeouts but the prompt does not disappear until the java-script finishes processing. If I don't make any page updates it disappears and the mouse shows script activity is executing.

Anyway around this?

Comment: ActiveX on a web page? Who would let an arbitrary web page to run an ActiveX?

Comment: it is an intranet application and security settings are set to disallow by default.

Comment: Well, it is always worth of mention in the question, if you're working on an intranet app. Unfortenately I don't have an answer, since it looks like I can't reproduce your issue. A small  code snippet might help, and also the used IE version would be nice to know.

Comment: var myDoc = new ActivexObject("Word.Application"); //ajax call to custom script $SP().Notify('Creating instance of MS Word'); //version use ie 9 as well as compatibilty mode.

Comment: Seems to work for me ... Do you seriously need help, or is this just a joke question?

Comment: sorry, I couldn't add line breaks.

Comment: Once the prompt appears and I select YES it stays on the page until all the scripts execute.

Comment: [A standard requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at SO. Also we need to know the used IE version. __Reproducible__ is a keyword ; ). We don't need all your code, just as much we can reproduce the issue. If you're using external resources, please describe them, if they are not obviously recoognizable in the code. In the question you're talking about FSO, in the comments it's a MSWord, which one causes troubles, or both?

Comment: I am processing a word document and saving as PDF. Since I am on a different network I can't give you more detail. Just suffice it to say there is much more script. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Sorry Teemu, I was using both FSO (copy file to temp directory) and MSWord objects. The point was not that the script was not working, it's just the prompt appears on screen much to long to allow me to inject notifications onto the web page.

Comment: The steps include creating FSO > copy file > create MS Word object > open document > save to PDF > create Outlook object > add new email and attach pdf to the message. With all this going on the Activex prompt stays visible on the page until the code finishes executing. I would like to get a handle on the prompt and get rid of it as the user does not know the page is processing the document. I have tried using setTimeout with up to a ten second delay before calling my next function and nothing works.